# F#: programmatically manipulating identifiers

Tags: f#, identifier, type-providers

I'm working with the [World Bank type provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/WorldBank.html), and trying to manipulate countries and indicators. Beginning with

```
let context = WorldBankDataProvider<"World Development Indicators">.GetDataContext ()
```

I can get a `Country` with

```
let france = context.Countries.France
```

and an `Indicator` predicated on that country with

```
let franceCAIndicator = france.Indicators.``Current account balance (% of GDP)``
```

Looking at the code for [`Runtime.WorldBank`](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/master/src/WorldBank/WorldBankRuntime.fs), it seems that an `Indicator` is by definition predicated upon a country, because it has an instance member `Code` which is set to a country or region code. But I'd like to be able to refer some kind of indicator-without-a-country object, and later combine it with a country. Perhaps an `IndicatorDescription` is what I seek? This yields an `IndicatorDescription`:

```
let CADescription = context.Topics.Trade.Indicators.``Current account balance (% of GDP)``
```

But how can I combine that with a `Country` to yield an `Indicator`? In the absence of a more elegant solution, is there a way to programmatically manipulate the identifier

```
``Current account balance (% of GDP)``
```

i.e. to bind it in some way to another identifier, and later construct the `Indicator`

```
france.Indicators.``Current account balance (% of GDP)``
```

from that identifier and `france`?

Comment: It sounds like the World Bank type provider might not be the right tool for doing what you want - it provides an easy access to certain aspects of the data, but not to other possible queries that you might want to do. What data do you actually want to get?